# Google play services and maps having update and compatibility issue

Tags: android, google-maps, dependencies, google-play-services

I'm getting this error while running my app:

> error: cannot access zzbgl class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

I have Google play services version 12.0.1 and Google play maps version 16.1.0.

When I tried updating to the most recent versions I got an error about installing the repositories and then it complained that this version is not supported.

Comment: can post your code, please?

Comment: Tried to help by fixing grammar and rewording the question a bit.

Always good to start with the problem, explain what you have tried and conclude with what you expected to happen.

There are some additional information you could provide like what are you using for updates, what was the repository error and what is the exact not supported version error and how did you realise that.

The more information you provide the easier to find someone that can help.